# Does .NET Task.Result block (synchronously) a thread?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, async-await, task

Does `Task.Result` **synchronously** block current thread such that it cannot be used to perform other operations while it is waiting for the task complete?

For example, if I call `Task.Result` in a ASP.NET execution path, the current thread cannot be used to process other requests while it's awaiting the result.

By the way, how about the `async` in C# 5.0? Does `await` in `async` method block the current thread?

Thanks for any comment.

Comment: Guess that's the difference between `await F` and `F.Result`. One is async the other is not.

Comment: @Emad, yes I guess that too. However, I would like to find a formal document or more detailed explanation about it.

Comment: Since you've obviously read [Task.Result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation before asking the question I think some deeper explanation is needed - as provided by linked duplicate.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

MSDN: [`Task<TResult>.Result` Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result)

> Accessing the property's get accessor blocks the calling thread until the asynchronous operation is complete; it is equivalent to calling the Wait method

MSDN: [await operator - asynchronously await for a task to complete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await)

> An await expression does not block the thread on which it is executing